# Redux-Saga unit testing select function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a lot of select statements that follow the following format:

```
const selector = (identifier) => (state) => state.getIn(['ui', identifier, 'object']);
```

The difference between the above and normal selectors, is I pass an identifier that populates the `getIn` call. So instead of doing `yield select(selector)` you do `yield select(selector(identifier))`

This works fine, but I can't seem to unit test it.

Usually you can just have the expected effect `select(selector)` and assert equal to that, e.g.

```
expect(generator.next().value).to.deep.equal(select(selector));
```

But that doesn't work when i'm trying to pass an identifier:

```
expect(generator.next().value).to.deep.equal(select(selector(identifier)));
```

I assume its something to do with when i'm calling the function, it returns different instances? But I would've thought deep equal solves that. Unfortunately - the error message I get doesn't provide any help.

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, SELECT) } to deeply equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, SELECT) }
```

Has anyone tried the above? or suggestion on how I can test this?

Thanks!

Comment: This assertion should fail, because reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating a new function every time, so you will not be able to test equality here - even with deep equality checks.

Alternative suggestion: Why don't you extract the selector function from the effect and execute it against an example state, really testing *what it does*?

Comment: I have tests like that - but here I am testing the sequence that saga effects are called - doesn't seem like there is a way to do it unfortunately.